How is the parameterization of the Klein bottle derived?
The parametric equations of the 3D immersion bottle (courtesy of Wikipedia) are:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
x(s,t) &= -\frac{2}{15} \Bigl[3\cos(t) - 30\cos(s) + 90\cos^4(s)\sin(s) \\
&\qquad\qquad - 60\cos^6(s)\sin(s) + 5\cos(s)\cos(t)\sin(t) \Bigr] \cos(s) \\
y(s,t) &= -\frac{1}{15} \Bigl[3\cos(s) - 3\cos^2(s)\cos(t) - 48\cos^4(s)\cos(t) + 48\cos^6(s)\cos(t) \\ 
&\qquad\qquad - 60\sin(s) + 5\cos(s)\sin(s)\cos(t) - 5\cos^3(s)\sin(s)\cos(t) \\ 
&\qquad\qquad - 80\cos^5(s)\sin(s)\cos(t) + 80\cos^7(s)\sin(s)\cos(t) \Bigr] \sin(s) \\
z(s,t) &= \frac{2}{15} \Bigl[3 + 5\cos(s)\sin(s)\Bigr] \sin(t) 
\end{aligned}$$
Here is what the equations look like when plotted with a 3D function grapher:

This is our classic Klein bottle. So how were these equations found?

To typeset sine and cosine, you can use the commands \sin and \cos.

Check here for a parametrisation of an embedding of the Klein bottle in dimension 4 https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355180/embedding-klein-bottles-in-4-space , it is much more simpler to understand, and even easier if you start by a Möbius band

The Wikipedia entry from which you copied that formula gives a reference. I would recommend that you read that published article.
